# How to get specific value within an array of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have an array (outside array) that contains three arrays (inside arrays), each of which have three elements.

```
array = [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
```

I want to select the specific inside array using an index of the outside array and then select the value within the selected inside array based off its index. Here is what I tried:

```
array.each_index{|i| puts "letter: #{array[i[3]]} " }
```

I was hoping that would give me the following output

```
letter: c letter: f letter: i
```

but instead, I get

```
letter: [[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g, h, i]]
```

I also tried

```
array.each_index{|i| puts "letter: #{array[i][3]} " }
```

but I get the same result. Please any suggestions are very appreciated. I need a simple explanation.

Answer (score 8):

`each_index` is an Enumerable which goes through all indices and performs an action on each one. When it's done it will return your **original collection** as it's not its job to change it. If you want to output stuff on the screen via `puts` / `print` then `each_index` is fine.

If you want to create a new collection as a result of going through all the elements of an original collection, you should use [map](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/map).

e.g.

```
array = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
new_array = array.map {|el| el[2]}
=> ["c", "f", "i"]
```

array.map iterates through array's elements so in every step |el| is an element, not an index, as in: `['a', 'b', 'c']` in the first iteration, `['d', 'e', 'f']` in the second one and so on...

Just pointing this out since I don't know what's the goal of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

do it like this:

```
array.each_index{|i| puts "letter: #{array[i][2]} " }
```

Since you want letter at index 2, not 3.

Also array should be defined like this:

```
array = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Comment: I actually meant to put 2 not 3 that was typo on my part... my actual code I am working on has 52 arrays within the main array (its a deck of cards, so index 0-51). I was hasty in trying to simplify it for this post.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `map` like so:

```
a = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
a.map(&:last)
# => ["c", "f", "i"]
```

Or if you really want the puts and not the collected values:

```
a.each {|v| puts "letter: #{v.last}"}
```

You could also use Ruby's `Matrix` class if there's more Matrix-y stuff you want to do:

```
require 'matrix'
m = Matrix[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
last_column = m.column_vectors.last
# => Vector["c", "f", "i"]
```

You can now use any of the `Vector` methods on `last_column`, including `to_a`, which will put you back in familiar territory with the last column's values.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in ruby are indexed from 0, not from 1. So:

```
array.each_index{|i| puts "letter: #{array[i][2]} " }
```

should give you what you want.

Comment: again that was a typo on my part my actual code has indexes 0-51 so I just got a bit hasty in writing out my question. What your writing there is what I initially thought would work, I mean it makes sense but for some reason its just not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below also:

```
p RUBY_VERSION

arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[11,12,13]]

arr.each{|x| p x; x.each_index{|i| p "Digit :: #{x[i]}" if i == 2} }
```

*output:*

```
"2.0.0"
[1, 2, 3]
"Digit :: 3"
[4, 5, 6]
"Digit :: 6"
[11, 12, 13]
"Digit :: 13
```

Comment: ahh this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for, I don't know why but I didn't think to nest the loops. Makes sense though, you have a nested array so why not nest the loops... good stuff. Although I like the other suggestions too because at some point I will need to modify the array and not just print it. But this answers my initial questions. Thank you!!